# Action describing a scalar field in a classical curved background

Tags: field-theory, computational-physics, action, software, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Been trying to derive equation (6.54) in *Quantum Fields in Curved Space* by N.D. Birrell & P.C.W. Davies (p. 162):
\begin{align}
 ^{(2)}H_{\mu\nu} &\equiv \frac{1}{(-g)^{1/2}}\frac{\delta}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}\int (-g)^{1/2}R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\beta} d^{n}x \\ &=R_{;\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\Box R-\Box R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu\nu}R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\beta}+2R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\beta\mu\nu} \\ &=2R_{\mu;\nu\alpha}^{\alpha}-\Box R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\Box R+2R_{\mu}^{\alpha}R_{\alpha\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R^{\alpha\beta}R_{\alpha\beta} 
\end{align}

by using the *xAct* package in *Mathematica*. The result (and part of the code used) can be seen in the picture attached below:
[image]

I am at a complete loss here; how are these last two terms equivalent? How do I go about transforming the expression I got using *Mathematica* to the one from the textbook?

Comment: Shouldn't you get the Einstein tensor as the variation? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @JamalS If one is given a regular Hilbert-Einstein action then yes, the Einstein tensor would be the the variation. However, when you're observing a quantum field in a classical curved space you'll get extra terms of higher curvature order: $$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} + \alpha^{(1)}H_{\mu\nu} +\beta^{(2)}H_{\mu\nu} + \gamma H_{\mu\nu}. $$ What I'm interested in is how to get these higher order members.

Comment: This is a quadratic action, so you will NOT get the Einstein tensor as the result.  But my question to @Kandrax is where is the scalar field?  The title doesn't make sense to me.  Without doing the work (again, as have long ago) I'd guess that either (1) the author used identities (such as Biannchi) to replace terms or made use of other equations derived from the action to evaluate the term on a particular solution.  I'm leaning towards option (1).

Comment: @ggcg The expected value of the energy-momentum tensor is on the other side of the equation.

Comment: I don't know how that answered my question.  You are asking how we get from the second line to the third, right?

Comment: @ggcg I answered before you edited your comment (either that or I simply didn't see the rest of the question in which case I apologize). Yes, you are correct in asking that.

Comment: @Kandrax, so have you tried using Biancchi identities to show equality?  Or are you still questioning the equality?

Comment: I seem to remember xAct needs help with Bianchi identities.  One can make one's own rules, however: RuleBianchiRicci = 
  MakeRule[{CD[-a]@RicciCD[a, b], 1/2 CD[b]@RicciScalarCD[]}, 
   UseSymmetries -> True, MetricOn -> All];

Comment: @ggcg Using Bianchi's identities I managed to reduce the last factor in the *Mathematica* code to $ -\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}\Box R $; the other factors remain a mistery.

Comment: @user2309840 Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Have you tried Maple's Tensor package?  I've used that for GR calculations, geodesic flows, geodesic deviation, field equations, etc.  I was raised on Maple but do not know how it compares to Mathematica for diff geom.